# Can Android image button use image retrieved from database?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I need image buttons with images that are downloaded from a database, i.e. not available at build time. All the imagebutton examples I've seen describe putting the images in the "drawable" folder, presumably at build time. Is it possible to load an image made/found at run time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You need to create a bitmap from a byte array (which you can read from a file or a database). Then convert the byte array into a `Bitmap`. Something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = bytesToBitmap(<your byte array here>);
ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

public static Bitmap bytesToBitmap(byte[] bytes)
{
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = null;

    try
    {
        imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("My Activity", "Unable to generate a bitmap: " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (imageStream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                imageStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And then use imageView instead of imageButton?

Comment: Use the `Bitmap` instead of the `BitmapDrawable`. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Insert image in DB using BLOB. You have convert that image in byte[] first.

```
private static final String SQL_GETCONTENTS = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "("+ 
                KEY_CONTENTSID + " TEXT," +
                KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";

public void addEntry( String id, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException{
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CONTENTSID, id);
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
}


public Cursor getEntry(String id ){
    String sql = "select * from " + DB_TABLE + " where " + KEY_CONTENTSID + "='" + id + "'";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Retrieve image and set:

```
Cursor c = entry.getEntry(idKey);
byte[] image =  c.getBlob(0);
BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
bfOptions.inDither = false;
bfOptions.inPurgeable = true;
bfOptions.inInputShareable = true;

thumbImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, bfOptions));
```

Using `BitmapFactory.Options` will help avoid some outofmemory exceptions.